# NHibernate: need to update object ID with @@identity after insert

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

I'm using NHibernate for the first time and struggling. On web page one, I start a form. I want to save and navigate to page two. How do I update my RequestForm object with the ID of the newly inserted row? It is still 0 when I call the redirect, though the data was persisted to the DB.

Here's my controller code:

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult New(RequestForm form)
    {
        // contract
        if (form == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Cannot be null", "form");
        }

        // validate the form
        form.Validate(ModelState);

        // if valid, save & continue
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var request = new Request();
            form.Update(request);
            repository.Save(request);
            return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Request", new {id = form.ID});
        }

        // if not valid, return new form
        return View("New", form);
    }
```

Here is the repository code:

```
    public void Save(T entity)
    {
        using (ISession session = GetSession())
        using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            session.SaveOrUpdate(entity);
            transaction.Commit();
        }
    }
```

Here's the relevant area of the mapping file:

```
<class
  name="Request"
  table="Data_Requests"
  dynamic-update="true">

<id 
  name="Id" 
  type="Int32" 
  access="property"
  column="RequestId"
  unsaved-value="0">
  <generator class="native"/>
</id>
```

Thanks for reading my question. I'm sure the answer is easy once you know what you are doing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - Dumb mistake

```
return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Request", new {id = form.ID});
```

Should be

```
return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Request", new {id = request.ID});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `<generator class="identity"/>`. It should work with native, but who knows...

Comment: Didn't work. Do you know if I have to do something to refresh the object? I thought it would just happen automagically...